# Omit theme loading of unused components and avoid network load in Vaadin 23

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I just realized that my Vaadin Web Application loads at least 3mb of unused JS theme libraries out of an 8Mb overall javascript network loading footprint.
How can this be prevented?

The three most prominent

- 1600kb vaadin charts `@vaadin_charts_theme_lumo_vaadin-chart__js.js`
- >340kb vaadin map `@vaadin_map_theme_lumo_vaadin-map__js.js`
- >310kb vaadin rich text editor `@vaadin_rich-text-editor_theme_lumo_vaadin-rich-text-editor__js.js`

Can this be excluded with Vite somehow?
Vaadin version: `23.3.4` (non-production mode)

[image: Network analysis ordered by size]

I am not using any of the commercial components and have tried to explicitly exclude them from the pom.xml and also removed them from package.json, then started `npm i` again

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin.addon</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-charts</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-rich-text-editor-flow</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-map-flow</artifactId>
            </exclusion> 
            <!-- [..] -->
```

Comment: Since you are not using commercial components, did you tried to replace vaadin artifact with vaadin-core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In development mode, a lot of extra JS is loaded. You should run your test in production mode where the application is scanned for the components you actually use and an optimized JS bundle is created.

There is usually no need to prevent some MB of JS from being loaded from localhost while developing.